# Character encoding failing

Tags: html, encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to set the encoding of some files in PHP to ISO-8859-1. I tried using this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`
```

but it still isn't working. What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Is this client side or server side because you're talking about <meta> which is HTML (client side) and PHP which is server side

Comment: “it still isn't working” — in what way is it not working? We need to know what you expect to see, and what you’re actually seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You should be outputting this as a real HTTP header.  `<meta>` elements are not a good substitute.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso8859-1');
```

You should ensure that the encoding of the files is actually ISO 8859-1 - all this does is tell the browser that the resource is in that encoding, it doesn't actually transcode or anything.